# How do I bind to this JList so I can change what gets displayed to the user?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList which i want to use to display a list a caches that are added in from another form, I've got this working and I want to be able to add the caches directly to the list... Is there a way to change what gets displayed to the user? or would it simply be a case of making to the toString method of my object what i want to be displayed?

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
{
    GeoGolfHole hole = (GeoGolfHole)arg;
    model.add(0, hole);
    jlHolesInGame.setText(Integer.toString(model.getSize()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new ListCellRenderer to render what you want out of the class.